# Split a Unicode string only at universal newlines (\n, \r, \r\n)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, the [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method splits at many line boundaries, including the "universal newlines" `"\r"`, `"\n"`, and `"\r\n"`, as well as others.

Suppose I have a Unicode string and I want to split it into lines, *only* recognizing universal newlines `"\r"`, `"\n"`, and `"\r\n"`. Example:

```
my_text = 'Line 1\f\rLine 2\r\nLine 3\f...\nLine 4\n'

# Desired output:
lines = split_only_universal_newlines(my_text)
print(lines)
# ['Line 1\x0c\r', 'Line 2\r\n', 'Line 3\x0c...\n', 'Line 4\n']
# Note that the form feed character \f is printed as '\x0c'.

# Incorrect output produced by str.splitlines:
lines = my_text.splitlines(keepends=True)
print(lines)
# ['Line 1\x0c', '\r', 'Line 2\r\n', 'Line 3\x0c', '...\n', 'Line 4\n']
```

The reason I need to only recognize universal newlines is for consistency with other code/tools that follow that convention.

What is the cleanest or most Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Probably `re.split`. I'm having a hard time what your expected output is here, though. Is it `['Line 1\f\r', 'Line 2\r\n', 'Line 3\f...\n', 'Line 4\n']`?

Comment: Yes that's the idea, `# Note that the form feed character \f is printed as '\x0c'.` (That's just how `print` works, but yes the first line should contain the form feed character `\f` inside it.)

Comment: So to be clear: you want to keep the newlines in your desired output?

Comment: Yes, similar to the `keepends=True` argument for `str.splitlines`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides regular expressions, there are two approaches that I can think of. The first is to employ `bytes.splitlines`, which according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-bytearray-operations) splits only universal newlines.

A solution based on this idea is as follows.

```
lines = [l.decode() for l in my_text.encode().splitlines(keepends=True)]
```

Another approach is to use the Text IO classes:

```
import io

lines = list(io.StringIO(my_text, newline=''))
```

Here, the `newline` keyword works as follows according to the [`io.StringIO` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

> The *newline* argument works like that of `TextIOWrapper`.

and the [`io.TextIOWrapper` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> When reading input from the stream, if *newline* is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. **If it is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated.** If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.

The latter approach looks better to me because it does not need to create another copy of the input string (like `my_text.encode()` does). Meanwhile, if you want to iterate over each line in the input you can just write:

```
for line in io.StringIO(my_text, newline=''):
    ...
```

Comment: The quoted sentence is actually defined under `TextIOWrapper` (and referred to by `StringIO`) which is in the middle of the section that I linked to. I did not know how to get a more specific link to that class so I gave the link to the whole section instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `io.StringIO(my_text, newline='').readlines()`. The `newline=''` means (only) universal newlines are treated as line separators, and furthermore line endings are returned to the caller unchanged.

```
import io
lines = io.StringIO(my_text, newline='').readlines()
print(lines)
# ['Line 1\x0c\r', 'Line 2\r\n', 'Line 3\x0c...\n', 'Line 4\n']
```

Python documentation:

- [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)
- [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines)
- [Behavior of `newline=''`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)